# how to change the item fontstyle inside the listbox item using c# and winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have list box with items....

```
                 say Listboxitem1
                     listboxitem2
                     listboxitem3...
```

Is it possible to change the item style of listboxitem1 ...

I have seen this code for changing the background colour of listbox selected item but i dint find any solution for changing the item style in listboxitem....

the below code is for changing the background colour of selected item in list box. but i dint find any property for changing item style(like font)

```
      if (e.Index < 0) return; 
    // if the item state is selected then change the back color  
    if ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected) 
        e = new DrawItemEventArgs(e.Graphics, 
                                  e.Font, 
                                  e.Bounds, 
                                  e.Index, 
                                  e.State ^ DrawItemState.Selected, 
                                  e.ForeColor, 
                                  Color.Red); // Choose the color 

    // Draw the background of the ListBox control for each item. 
    e.DrawBackground(); 
    // Draw the current item text 
    e.Graphics.DrawString(listbox1.Items[e.Index].ToString(), e.Font, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds, StringFormat.GenericDefault); 
    // If the ListBox has focus, draw a focus rectangle around the selected item. 
    e.DrawFocusRectangle();
```

can any one have idea about this..

Many thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you see the e.Font in your own code? Just use another font in there ;)

Comment: i have tried like this "fontstyle.bold" in place of e.font but it does not working ....by using this  one you can change the font style only selected items not all items .....is there any other option.....

Comment: look - I do not see where this code is located but I guess it's in the Userdraw of the item right? If yes then you can do as I said. Just try with a "Font" not a Fontstyle in place of e.Font on the e.Graphics.DrawString code. You have to provide something like 'new Font(e.Font, FontStyle.Bold)'

Comment: do u mean, i need to change at this line....e.Graphics.DrawString(listbox1.Items[e.Index].ToString(), e.Font, Brushes.Black, e.Bounds, StringFormat.GenericDefault);

Comment: yes the other one will only change the font on the selected item (it just replaces the current eventargs-parameter)